# How to use a if/else to click on IOS button if it appears on the Screen

Tags: java, ios, xpath, appium

Hi every time the app is updated to a new version it should show a message about the terms that the user has to accept before using the app. But if he already accepted the message in a previous version it won't show up anymore.
[image: screenshot]

I tried to do a restriction like this:

```
Boolean Allow = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//[@id=‘Allow’]")).size()<0;
if (Allow.TRUE) {
new WebDriverWait(driver, 30, esperandogif).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//[@text=‘Allow’]"))).click();
else {
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@text=‘Cadastre-se com seu e-mail pessoal’]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@placeholder=‘Email’]")).sendKeys("ashutosh@ashutosh.com.br");
driver.swipe(165, 759, 175, 534, 1234);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@placeholder=‘Senha’]")).sendKeys(“lucasmoreira”);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@placeholder=‘Confirmer Senha’]")).sendKeys(“lucazmoreira”);
driver.swipe(309, 856, 390, 406, 888);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@placeholder=‘Nome e Sobrenome’]")).sendKeys(“teste”);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@placeholder=‘CPF’]")).sendKeys(“12345678901”);
driver.swipe(168, 946, 334, 615, 2240);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@placeholder=‘Data de Nascimento (dd/mm/aaaa)’]")).click();
try{Thread.sleep(threadSleep);} catch(Exception ignore){}
//driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@text=‘2018’]")).click();
// driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@text=‘2020’]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id=‘Feito’]")).click();
driver.swipe(84, 887, 259, 493, 1461);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@placeholder=‘Telefone’]")).sendKeys(“99999999999”);
driver.swipe(450, 812, 500, 640, 1292);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id=‘Cadastrar’]")).click();
System.out.println(“report URL : " + driver.getCapabilities().getCapability(“reportUrl”));
driver.quit();
}
```

But it’s not working. If it doesn’t show up on the screen the code fails and it doesn’t click on driver.findElement(By.xpath(”//*[@text=‘Cadastre-se com seu e-mail pessoal’]")).click();
How can I do that restriction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your comparison is turned the wrong way. First line should be greater than 0, not less than.

```
Boolean Allow = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//[@id=‘Allow’]")).size()>0;
```

You should probably also find by id since it's available to you.

```
Boolean Allow = driver.findElements(By.id("Allow")).size()>0;
```

I write such statements with isEmpty() and find them a bit more readable and not prone to this error:

```
Boolean Allow = !driver.findElementsById("Allow")).isEmpty();
```

Comment: To add to this answer, if you use `By.id` with Appium, and this is a native app (you don't seem to mention that part) then it will be able to locate the element, but with a `By.xpath` it will only match tagname "id" and not find "resource-id", which is probably what it really is.